# How to extract all Twitter feeds of sinhala language language only using python?

Tags: python, tweepy, tweets

I want to extract all Twitter feeds of a specific language only. (to extract Sinhala language tweets) How can I do that using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regex` is useful.
Sinhala language use codes `U+0D80`～`U+0DFF` in `utf-8`. First, try extracting tweets that contain Sinhala characters with regex.